# What is the true nature of the Cervello?

Tags: reborn

The last time the Cervello appear in the manga is when

> they give Byakuran the Mare Rings.

After this, they're not shown or mentioned again.  While their true purpose could be inferred from the events in the final arc, I'd like to know if there's any official word on this.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you asking exactly? The current answer to your question will be either "Yes" or "No". Please rephrase your question.

Comment: I rephrased it.  Does that work better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing official from either the manga or anime.

Anything regarding the Cervello's true nature will only be speculation and can thus be dependent on the viewers' interpretations.

While Shoichi said that the Cervello ended up with the Millefiore at some point (Episode 169: Sky Lion Ver.V (Leone di Cielo Version Vongola), it could be implied that this happened after they gave Byakuran the Mare Rings.

[image: Cervello ended up with the Millefiore at some point.]

In my opinion, their true nature is similar to that of Kawahira's; they're just administrators. I'd like to assume that since Kawahira gave the Vongola Rings to Giotto, he has somehow given it to the Cervello to administer since he's administering the Arcobaleno pacifiers.